# Получить название купона в заказе woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Нужно получить название использованного в заказе купона. Для наглядности вывожу под продуктами на той же странице заказа. При поиске решения окончательно запутался, потому что некоторые методы уже устаревшие. Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Вот пример того, что есть на данный момент:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_itemmeta', 'so_32457241_after_order_itemmeta', 10, 3 );
function so_32457241_after_order_itemmeta( $post_id ){
// Get an instance of WC_Order object
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

// Coupons used in the order LOOP (as they can be multiple)
foreach( $order->get_coupon_codes() as $coupon_code ){

    // Retrieving the coupon ID
    $coupon_post_obj = get_page_by_title($coupon_code, OBJECT, 'shop_coupon');
    $coupon_id       = $coupon_post_obj->ID;

    // Get an instance of WC_Coupon object in an array(necessary to use WC_Coupon methods)
    $coupon = new WC_Coupon($coupon_id);
    return $coupon;
}
echo $coupon;}
```

Но в итоге выдаётся ошибка Call to a member function get_coupon_codes() on bool.
Я очень мало понимаю в WordPress, заранее спасибо!

**Update**: Основная моя задача - добавить к передаче данных из заказа, помимо адреса, телефона и тд., ещё и использованный пользователем купон. Вот так выглядит функция в плагине:

```
public static function get_data_order_address($order_id)
{
    $order   = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $address = '';

    if ($order->get_billing_postcode()) {
        $address .= $order->get_billing_postcode();
    }

    if ($order->get_billing_state()) {
        $address .= ', ' . $order->get_billing_state();
    }

    return $address;
}
```

Я хочу добавить следом похожую функцию, с передачей купона, по типу

```
public static function get_data_order_coupons($order_id)
{
    $order   = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $coupons = [];

    if ($order->get_used_coupons()) {
        $coupons .= $order->get_used_coupons();
    }

    return $coupons;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас в заголовке функции `$post_id`, а дальше в коде - `$order_id`. Откуда ж ему взяться, ордеру? Замените заголовок на

```
function so_32457241_after_order_itemmeta( $order_id ){
```

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, но всё ещё во всех случаях выдаётся та же ошибка 'Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_coupon_codes() on bool'. Так же происходит с get_used_coupons()

Comment: У вас и фильтр неправильный. Вы откуда такой код взяли? В этот фильтр order не передаётся вообще. Вам в какой момент надо получить купоны в заказе? При создании заказа, после его оплаты, завершения - когда?

Comment: Добавил дополнение к объяснению

Answer (score 0):

У себя в проекте использовал следующую конструкцию:

- В div с классом `coupon-amount` выводится числовое значение купона.
- В div с классом `coupon-name` выводится код купона (название).

Эти параметры можно передавать вместе с данными через форму оформления заказа. Тег `div` меняете на `input`, `input` присваиваете атрибут `name`, например `name="promo"`:

```
<?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_coupons() as $code => $coupon ) : ?>                
                <div class="coupon-amount"><?php wc_cart_totals_coupon_html( $coupon ); ?></div>
                <div class="coupon-name-wraper">
                    <div class="coupon-name"><?php wc_cart_totals_coupon_label( $coupon ); ?></div>
                    <button class="coupon-copy">Скопировать</button>
                </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>

/**
 * Выводим значение поля на странице редактирования заказа, functions.php
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
        // Промо
        echo '<p><strong>'.__('Купон').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'promo', true ) . '</p>';
}
```